# Reduce result of `find` to top level results

Tags: bash, find

I have a find expression looking for `node_modules` directories. Some of the results are `node_modules` directories within a parent `node_modules` directory.

I'm only interested in finding the top most `node_modules` directory and performing an action on it, i.e. add a `.metadata_never_index` file so that Spotlight (macOS) doesn't index it.

I'm struggling to find a solution which deals with this; can find do this for me, or do I need to calculate it manually (maybe through string manipulations)?

As a bonus, I'd like to ignore all folders which already contain the `.metadata_never_index` file, if possible.

*EDIT*: Some context; this will run as a cron job and periodically look for `node_modules` in my `~/Sites` directory, i.e multiple top-level projects.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more searching, I found a solution on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/736451).

To summarise Paxali's answer:

> `find /home/code -type d -name ".git" | grep -v '\.git/'`
>
> In english: find me all directories named ".git" and filter out any occurences in the resultlist which contain ".git/" (dot git slash).

Except in my case, I used `node_modules/` instead of `.git/`.

My working code:

```
find -f ~/Sites . -name node_modules | grep -v 'node_modules/' | while read fname; do
    touch $fname/.metadata_never_index
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the top most modules can be found by using

npm command  with flag --depth

> npm list --depth=0

you can also create aliases as follows:

```
alias ng="npm list -g --depth=0 2>/dev/null"
alias nl="npm list --depth=0 2>/dev/null"
```

Comment: This assumes I'm in the project folder already does it not? I'm looking to achieve this for all instances of a `node_modules` folder (i.e multiple top level projects) starting from a known directory (i.e. ~/).